# Acc always around 0.5 by using binary neural network with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
Reading Image Data
file_dirs = ["./Positive", "./Negative"]

def read_image_data(file_dir):
    files = []
    for i in range(20000):
        img_no = "%05d"% (i+1) 
        img_dir = file_dir + "/" + img_no + ".jpg"
        img = cv2.imread(img_dir,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        if img is not None:
            files.append(img)
            continue
        img_dir = file_dir + "/" + img_no + "_1" + ".jpg"
        img = cv2.imread(img_dir,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        files.append(img)
    return np.array(files)
pos = read_image_data(file_dirs[0])
neg = read_image_data(file_dirs[1])

print(type(pos[0])) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(pos.shape[0]) # 20000
print(pos[0].shape) # 227,227

pos_label = np.array([np.float32(1),np.float32(0)])
neg_label = np.array([np.float32(0),np.float32(1)])
pos_labels = np.array([pos_label for i in range(20000)]) # [1,0],[1,0], ...
neg_labels = np.array([neg_label for i in range(20000)]) # [0,1],[0,1], ...

# combine two pos and neg to one dataset
x = np.concatenate((pos,neg))
y = np.concatenate((pos_labels,neg_labels))
  
# Preprocessing
# expand dims
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=3)
print(x.shape) # (40000,227,227,1)

def shuffle(dataset, labels, NUM_SAMPLES):
    np.random.seed(10)
    random_list = np.arange(NUM_SAMPLES)
    np.random.shuffle(random_list)
    return dataset[random_list], labels[random_list], random_list

# rate = percentage of training data in the dataset
def data_split(x, y, rate, NUM_SAMPLES):
    rate = int(rate*NUM_SAMPLES)
    x_train = x[:rate]
    x_test = x[rate:]
    y_train = y[:rate]
    y_test = y[rate:]
    return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test

# shuffle and split into train and validation datasets
x_shuffled, y_shuffled, random_list = shuffle(x, y, x.shape[0])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = data_split(x_shuffled, y_shuffled, 0.8, x.shape[0])

# normalization
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0, y_train, y_test 

def get_model(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, NUM_CATEGORIES):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,1), activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="tanh"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="tanh"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="sigmoid"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES*16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES*8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES, activation='softmax'))
    
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = get_model(227,227,2)

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)           (None, 225, 225, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_20 (Averag (None, 112, 112, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, 110, 110, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_21 (Averag (None, 55, 55, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_10 (Dropout)         (None, 55, 55, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)           (None, 53, 53, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_22 (Averag (None, 26, 26, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_11 (Dropout)         (None, 26, 26, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_23 (Averag (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 32)                294944    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 16)                528       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 34        
=================================================================
Total params: 356,018
Trainable params: 356,018
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
Epoch 1/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 16s 16ms/step - loss: 3.0167 - accuracy: 0.5013
Epoch 2/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 15s 15ms/step - loss: 0.6963 - accuracy: 0.4942
Epoch 3/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 15s 15ms/step - loss: 0.6953 - accuracy: 0.5016
Epoch 4/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 15s 15ms/step - loss: 0.6957 - accuracy: 0.4999
Epoch 5/5
 679/1000 [===================>..........] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6947 - accuracy: 0.4983
```

Hi. I'm quite new to tensorflow.

I want to build a CNN for classifying photos with surface crack and photos without surface crack.

Why does my model always show a result of acc:0.5?

Even I have tried different learning rate, different activation function, different types of output such as one-hot encoding and sparse categories (0 or 1) increasing the width and the depth of the network, number of neuron = 1 in the last dense layer with sigmoid, it also shows the same result.

Comment: 1. Loss not reducing is an indication that your neural network is not learning. The Adam optimizer that you are using has a default learning rate of 0.001. Please try using the detail value before trying to modify it. 2. If this is a binary classification problem (predicting one of two classes), then the activation function that is used in the last dense layer is generally 'sigmoid' and the number of units should be 1 [model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))]. Softmax activation function is used in the last dense layer for multi class classification (more than 2 classes).

Comment: for q1, since I was considering about whether it's trapped in a local maxima, so I tuned it so big.
for q2, I have also tried. It just kept having the acc ard 0.5.
anyway, thanks for you output

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make a few changes in your code for better accuracy as below:

- Change all the `activation = 'relu'` except in the last dense layer.
- Remove all the `dropout` layers from the model.
- Keep the default
  `learning_rate=0.001` for Adam optimizer.
- Use `sigmoid` activation function in last layer as this model is for **Binary Classification** and you are using 'Binary Crossentropy' loss function while compiling the model

**Please check this below updated code:**

```
def get_model(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,NUM_CATEGORIES):

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,1), activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))   
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='valid', activation="relu"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES*32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CATEGORIES*32, activation='relu'))   
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))   
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = get_model(227,227,2)

model.summary()

model.fit(train_dataset,validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=10)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
63/63 [==============================] - 9s 118ms/step - loss: 1.9775 - accuracy: 0.5405 - val_loss: 0.6941 - val_accuracy: 0.5710
Epoch 2/10
63/63 [==============================] - 8s 119ms/step - loss: 0.6599 - accuracy: 0.6175 - val_loss: 0.6715 - val_accuracy: 0.6020
Epoch 3/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 75ms/step - loss: 0.6303 - accuracy: 0.6470 - val_loss: 0.6673 - val_accuracy: 0.6310
Epoch 4/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 74ms/step - loss: 0.6029 - accuracy: 0.6775 - val_loss: 0.7275 - val_accuracy: 0.5780
Epoch 5/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 73ms/step - loss: 0.5639 - accuracy: 0.7080 - val_loss: 0.6710 - val_accuracy: 0.6490
Epoch 6/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 73ms/step - loss: 0.5356 - accuracy: 0.7325 - val_loss: 0.8324 - val_accuracy: 0.6200
Epoch 7/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 73ms/step - loss: 0.5034 - accuracy: 0.7500 - val_loss: 0.7696 - val_accuracy: 0.6430
Epoch 8/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 74ms/step - loss: 0.4664 - accuracy: 0.7790 - val_loss: 0.7539 - val_accuracy: 0.6530
Epoch 9/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 73ms/step - loss: 0.4004 - accuracy: 0.8105 - val_loss: 0.7225 - val_accuracy: 0.6570
Epoch 10/10
63/63 [==============================] - 5s 76ms/step - loss: 0.3409 - accuracy: 0.8455 - val_loss: 0.7910 - val_accuracy: 0.6510
```